# echo-server with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, echo-server

I have ASP.NET server.

I have an embedded device with cellular communication (socket based) - the device is not a web-browser.

I want to be able to access an ASP.NET page (`.aspx`) and get a reply.

To begin with, I want to send binary data `\x11\x22\x33` and get the same reply from the server (echo-server).

Any guidelines on how to implement the ASP.NET code or a reference to similar project will help too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET runs in the IIS webserver context. If you want to process a request using ASP.NET, it has to be an HTTP request. You can echo the content of the HTTP request in the HTTP response, but it won't be a real echo server.

Alternatively, you can make an echo server using .NET, without using ASP.NET and without a webserver.